# How do I login on an ubuntu-cloud instance deployed on an Openstack infrastructure

Tags: openstack

I've tried deploying an ubuntu-cloud instance on an Openstack Newton infrastructure and it works just fine and I'm accessing it with the novnc url, but I can't login into it, because the credentials seem to be wrong (I've tried with 'ubuntu' for both the user and the password). How can I login into the VM instance? I've already tried specifying custom credentials with an user-data file when using the `openstack server create` command, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default password for logging into Ubuntu cloud images (because that would be a tremendous security problem). You are expected to configure an ssh keypair in Nova, specify that when creating the instance via the `--key-name` argument to `openstack server create`, and then authenticate with that key when logging in.

You will need to ensure that your security group rules permit ssh access, and you will probably need to assign a floating ip to the instance in order to be able to connect to it.

You can certainly decide instead to create a user and password in your user-data script. If you're trying that and it's not working, you'll want to update your question to include the actual script you're using so that we can help you figure out what's going on.